# Where to put network calls in a react+redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to get some thoughts on what people would consider the best practices for how people organize network calls in their react+redux apps. I usually let my components make the calls, get data and then pass that into an action that will get reduced. Is this the best practice or is it better to separate networking out of my components and place that logic somewhere else in the app, maybe in the reducers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to make network calls is in your action creators. However, you're going to need some middleware to make that work best. Take a look at this [promise-middleware](https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial/blob/master/11_src/src/promise-middleware.js) (in fact, I'd suggest checking out that whole tutorial). If you use that middleware, you can have action creators that return a promise and also have three action types - one for the request, one to handle successful responses, and one to handle failed requests. Then you just listen for those 3 actions in your reducers.

So with that middleware, you could have an action creator like this:

```
function networkCall() {
    return {
        types: ['MAKE_REQUEST', 'REQUEST_SUCCESS', 'REQUEST_FAILURE'],
        promise: () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'example.com/api'
                    type: 'GET'
                });
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you are free to build your own promise middleware, but that should set you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one thing that was done right in Angular. You have all your network calls neatly placed in your `services`. This can easily be done in Redux.

The docs rightly suggest that network calls are in your `actions`. I'd factor them out into a separate place, you can call it "services". There you would define all your constants such as your API server URL, authentication-related stuff, etc. This would be the only place that is aware of the implementation details of your network calls - which library you use (jQuery, axios, superagent, etc).

Your actions files would import function from those services and call them. If you decide later on to swap out your networking library, you wouldn't have to change your `actions`.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much follow the pattern of the actions in the [redux tutorials for Async Actions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Td-2D-_7Y2E). It makes most sense to me to keep everything async in the actions --  away from both the components and the store/reducers.

I also use [Redux Crud](https://github.com/Versent/redux-crud) to standardize the actions related to network actions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an API middleware, either [`redux-api-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware) or something of your own (it isn't very hard to [write one](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/Middleware.md)).

Then, for example, your action creators could return actions like

```
{type: 'API_GET', url: '/api/userList', nextType: 'USER_LIST'}
```

...that would be later handled by a middleware that would send the actual request and then dispatch a new action like:

```
{type: 'USER_LIST_FETCHED', status: 200, payload: [{id: 1, ...}, ...]}
{type: 'USER_LIST_FAILED', status: 404, payload: {message: '...'}}
```